# How to tweak default Gnome to make it look like ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Ubuntu comes with Gnome with a modified theme + some extensions enabled by default. Where could I download this theme and what is the list of extensions and tweaks to apply on a default Gnome to make it look like Ubuntu gnome?

Answer (score 2):

The default theme is called Yaru. Development happens at https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru . You can find the rest of the defaults by looking at `apt show ubuntu-desktop`.

```
$ apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | grep yaru
  Recommends: libreoffice-style-yaru
  Recommends: yaru-theme-gnome-shell
  Recommends: yaru-theme-gtk
  Recommends: yaru-theme-icon
  Recommends: yaru-theme-sound
$ apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | grep extension
  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-tiling-assistant
```

You can install them with `apt install`, but if you just want to download the Ubuntu-specific versions, you can do `apt download` and open them in Archive Manager.